# Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock IV

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iv/

```
public int maxProfit(int k, int[] prices) {        
    int[] buy = new int[k + 1], sell = new int[k + 1];
    Arrays.fill(buy, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    for (int price : prices) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            buy[i] = Math.max(buy[i], sell[i - 1] - price);
            sell[i] = Math.max(sell[i], buy[i] + price);
        }
    }
    return sell[k];
}
```

Question 1)
I understand most of the solution but I'm a bit confused about the `sell[i]` state. For example, when we buy a stock in `buy[i]`, it is calculated by `sell[i - 1] - price` which means max profit of sell from the previous day minus the cost of buying the stock today.

However, when we buy a stock in sell[i], it is `buy[i] + price` instead of `buy[i-1]`. If we want sell today, shouldn't it be max profit of buy from yesterday + today's price? So wondering why there is a lack of + 1 when calculating `sell[i]`.

Question 2)
Instead of buying or selling we can also choose to hold and do nothing where this is expressed as buy[i]/sell[i]. However, if we don't do anything today, shouldn't the number be a duplicate from the previous day? `buy[i+1]/sell[i+1]`. Just wondering why it's buy[i] and not buy[i-1] since in other stock problems, when you choose to do nothing, you grab the value from the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the index `i` goes from `1` to the number of allowed transactions `k`. It means that in this solution `i - 1` is not the previous day, it's the previous transaction.

At the start of each external loop iteration the `buy` and `sell` arrays already store the values from the previous day. So in the internal loop before updating `buy[i]` and `sell[i]` the values at that index come from the previous day.

So the meaning of the lines in the internal loop is actually like this:

```
buy[i] =                  // the best funds after buying in the i-th transaction is
  Math.max(               // the max of
    buy[i],               // not buying today at all, 
                          // i.e. just copy the value from yesterday
    sell[i - 1] - price); // or buying for today's price with the funds 
                          // after selling in the **previous** transaction
sell[i] =                 // the best funds after selling in the i-th transaction is
  Math.max(               // the max of
    sell[i],              // not selling today at all, 
                          // i.e. just copy the value from yesterday
    buy[i] + price);      // or selling for today's price with the funds
                          // after buying in the **current** transaction
```

Note that buying and selling in one transaction in the same day is actually not a problem. The price is the same, so it means we just ignore the `i`-th transaction. This means that in the end `sell[k]` will contain the best profit after `k` or **fewer** transactions. That's fine: for example in the first example test case `k = 2, prices = [2,4,1]` we use only one of the 2 allowed transactions.